Web Application & API Data comparison by using seleuium one test code?
How to test Web Application & API Data comparison by using seleuium one test code  for a lot of records of rows and columns ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why use these tools to test/verify content? That's not something you want to do. Instead, you want to focus on the process of how the content is created, read, updated, destroyed (CRUD). That will be more meaningful tests!

One architectural approach you may want to look is Dave Farley's
DSL approach (short explanation and long explanation).

With it, you can will have your test descriptions and the DSL code that implements it. You would have two protocol drivers implementing the same interface: One for the web page and one for the API.
Your tests will call the same flows on both protocol drivers and receive domain objects of the same type as response. Then you can compare these objects in your assertions.
val webLoginData = ProtocolDriverFactory().createDriverForWeb().performLogin();
val apiLoginData = ProtocolDriverFactory().createDriverForApi().performLogin();
assertThat(webLoginData).isEqualTo(apiLoginData);

